# Module has no exported member, 'Request'

Tags: javascript, express

I see there are a ton of posts on this topic, but I didn't see any related to Express and my particular issue, which is:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import { Request, Response, Application } from 'express';  // <-- Error here
```

gives me an error (`Module has no imported member` for `'Request'`, `'Response'` and `'Application')`.

I see that in `node_modules` there are the files `request.js`, `response.js`, and `application.js` listed in the `/lib` sub-directory. Based on the error trace, my guess is that Express is not checking in the `/lib` sub-directory. How can I force/guide the system to check in the `/lib` sub-directory when using `import`? (Or is that not the problem and there's another problem altogether?).

I tried `import { Request, Response, Application } from 'express/lib'`, and `import * as expressLib from 'express/lib` and then `import {Request, Response, Application } from expressLib`, but neither of those worked.

---

Note: I have the following code below the `imports` . . . Because `Request` and `Response` are Object types, I assume they should be left in upper-case?

```
import * as express from 'express';
// import * as expressLib from 'express/lib'
import { Request, Response, Application } from 'express';
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
import * as jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import * as fs from "fs";

const app: Application = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());

app.route('api/login')
    .post(loginRoute);

const RSA_PRIVATE_KEY = fs.readFileSync('/demos/private.key');


export function loginRoute(req: Request, res: Response) {

    const email = req.body.email, 
        password = req.body.password;

        if (validateEmailAndPassword()) {
            const userId = findUserIdForEmail(email);

            const jwtBearerToken = jwt.sign({}, RSA_PRIVATE_KEY, {
                algorithm: 'RS256',
                expiresIn: 120,
                subject: userId
            });
            // res.cookie("SESSIONID", jwtBearerToken, {httpOnly: true, secure: true});

            res.status(300).json({
                idToken: jwtBearerToken,
                expiresIn: ""
            })
        } else {
            res.sendStatus(401);
        }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Updated: I didn't realize that you use typescript, please disregard the original answer.

With typescript the capitalized imports should work if you have installed [@types/express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express) - because this package exports capitalized types: https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/express/index.d.ts#L86

Probably before the restart the types package has not been indexed somehow. This is the only guess that I have taking into account that the issue has been resolved.

=======================================

When a module is imported - the file listed as the [main](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#main) is the `package.json` is loaded. If there is no `main` file in the `package.json` then `index.js` from the module root directory is loaded.

In case of express there is no `main` file and `index.js` loads `./lib/express`:
https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/index.js

```
module.exports = require('./lib/express');
```

By checking `./lib/express` we can see that it exports `request`, `response` and `application` in lowercase:
https://github.com/expressjs/express/blob/master/lib/express.js#L59:

```
/**
 * Expose the prototypes.
 */

exports.application = proto;
exports.request = req;
exports.response = res;
```

So in order to import them you should use lowercase:

```
import { response, request, application } from 'express';
```

Comment: Many thanks for your answer. But now I'm really confused. I just re-started my machine without making any changes, and now, surprisingly, `import { Request, Response, Application } from 'express'` in upper-case works. Also, I edited my OP as above to provide a bit more details why I think these should be upper-case. Many thanks in advance for taking a look.

Comment: @Crowdpleasr Hi, thanks for the getting back. I have not realized that you use typescript, sorry for the confusion. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You want to lower case 'Request', 'Response', and 'Application'.

When i run this code:

```
console.log('a',express.application);
console.log('A',express.Application);

console.log('req',express.request);
console.log('Req',express.Request);

console.log('res',express.response);
console.log('Res',express.Response);
```

I get `undefined` for the 'A', 'Req', and 'Res'.

(I would have made this a comment, but I cannot leave comments.)

Comment: Many thanks for your reply. Please see my edits to the OP.

Comment: Honestly, I get an error on the first line when I run `node index.js`:
```
import * as express from 'express';
       ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token *
```
Could you post your code and the specific errors?
Maybe also include a link to example you are trying to follow.

Comment: That's basically the full code above, added to my OP. The link to the article I'm trying to follow is: <https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-jwt-authentication/>. It's so strange that re-starting solved the problem, and following your and @antonku's troubleshooting steps would definitely indicate that `Request`and `Response` should be in lower-case, but somehow in upper-case it suddenly now works. Very perplexing!

Comment: I can't help you any further then. I get an error on the first line. Without more help from you I can't do any better. 

If you post the exact code and the exact error the internet-help-machine will basically write any code you want. ;)

Comment: Oops. My bad. I thought I'd posted the full code in, but I hadn't saved it. I just saved it now.